# (Bundler::GemRequireError) Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant AbstractController::Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid-rails

I'm using Rails 5.0.0.beta3, everything works well, after I integrated [sendgrid-rails](https://github.com/PavelTyk/sendgrid-rails) I got this exception when running `rspec`

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sendgrid-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant AbstractController::Rendering
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:204:in `<class:Base>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:11:in `<class:TestCase>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:10:in `<module:ActionView>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-0.1.1/lib/rails-controller-testing.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Users/hieupham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
```

I think this only happens with Rails 5, Do you have any experience with this kind of issue?

How to fix this? Btw, I raised an [issue](https://github.com/PavelTyk/sendgrid-rails/issues/21) for the author as well

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved this issue by:

**Add `require false` to gemfile**

```
group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', :require => false
end
```

**Require the gem in the `test_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb` after others**

```
# Other configs
require 'rails-controller-testing'
```

Ref to this [recommendation](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing/issues/22)

Comment: Are you using minitest too? If not, I expect you don't need those other includes.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Thanks, I just updated the answer to make sure it clear